# Как получить имена все товаров ?

Tags: javascript

Хочу  получить только  имена объектов (cat, dog, bird)

```js
var storage = [
{cat: {name: "Garfield", count: 3443, price: 1000}},
{bird: {name: "Eagle", count: 4042, price: 3000}},
{dog: {name: "Rex", count: 1488, price: 2000}}
];

function  getAllProductNames(storage) {
    var keys = [];
    for(var key in storage) {
        keys.push(key);
        if(typeof storage[key] === "object") {
            var subkeys = getAllProductNames(storage[key]);
            keys = keys.concat(subkeys.map(function(subkey) {
                return key + "." + subkey;
            }));
        }
    }
    console.log(keys);
    return keys;
}
getAllProductNames(storage);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var keys = Object.keys(storage);
```